# How to install plugins to play media files of the following type : application/x-shockwave-flash decoder?

Tags: 15.10, video, flash

How to install plugins to play media files of the following type :
application/x-shockwave-flash decoder ? Actually I wanted to download  online videos of website hotstar.com . Those videos need adobe flash player to run. I downloaded those videos from hotstar.com in the file extension .swf and now I need to run it and I don't know how. I tried it with gnash swf viewer but it didn't work and tried with some browsers also but they also didn't work.So I am trying it with Videos (the default videos software of ubuntu).But now it says that the videos require to install plugins to play media files of the type : application/x-shockwave-flash decoder and now it says plugins can't be downloaded.
If no one knows how to install the plugins then please say how to open videos of file extension .swf ? Do something , please ? Details of ubuntu desktop :-

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 15.10

Release:    15.10

Codename:   wily

OS Type : 32 bit

Comment: Bump \${}{}{}{}\$.